# Save part of an image in C#?

Tags: c#, bitmap

Well, I'm studying bitmaps, and I downloaded a pdf which said an image was an array of pixels. Since it is an array (which is quite logical) there is how to define points within the image, mark a region say so. The bitmap class as well should know how to read the properties of an image, such as the "size" of it, I wonder if there is any way to score points like 200x200 (example) and save that region into a new image.

The image of Braum, character of the game League of Legends, is random and this mark in black is to show what it would be this region which I mean.

image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFCoX.png

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: It seems like you are referring to an image, without providing the image. Could you take another look?

Comment: @royalTS nothing.so far is just one think, sorry the english. I don't speak  good

Comment: @Carlos with the bitmap class you can get the values for each pixel or a range of pixels (rectangle e.g.) and it allows you to save these informations to a new bitmap

Comment: @royalTS You give me an example and respond to mark as correct?

Comment: @Carlos I am sorry but this all I can up with at the moment (no PC): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457087.aspx